# using "OneVsRestClassifier" from sklearn in Python to tune a customized binary classification into a multi-class classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I have binary classification method name Fclassifier I need to apply it in a multi-class classification problem, this classifier doesn't have any decision_function (or predict_proba) and its core only accept {1,-1} as class labels! I am trying to use **OneVsRestClassifier** multi-classifier from sklearn so that I can tune the Fclassifier into multi-class classifier:

```
fm = FClassification(n_iter=1000, init_stdev=0.1, rank=2, random_state=123,l2_reg_w=0, l2_reg_V=0, l2_reg=0, step_size=0.1)
OneVsRestClassifier(fm).fit(X_train,y_train)
```

but I am facing the following error:

> RuntimeError: Cannot clone object FClassification(init_stdev=0.1,
>   l2_reg=None, l2_reg_V=0, l2_reg_w=0,
>            n_iter=1000, random_state=123, rank=2, step_size=0.1), as the constructor does not seem to set parameter l2_reg_V

do you think if it is the problem of **Fclassifier** that can not satisfy the expectation of **OneVsRestClassifier** and if I should define a customized **predict_proba** which can fit my data to the classifier in order to solve the problem? or if the error may have other reasons and solutions?

Comment: Have you solved this question？
I have a same question now

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to implement `get_params` method to export all your hyper-parameters or inherit your classifier from `sklearn.base.BaseEstimator` since under hood of `OneVsRestClassifier`, every classifier is being distributed. so your classifier is being cloned.